# Find largest TimeSpan in range that don't overlap with data-table-posts

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to find the largest cohesive time for non-working-hours diff in a specific range.

The range that is looked at is defined by:
sDate = range start
eDate = range end

in this defined range, there could be existing registrations (orange blocks in image).

Could someone please give me some input on how to solve this issue.

[image]

This code will not compare existing post with each other.

```
 public TimeSpan TimeNightRest(DateTime WhatDay, int dayRange, DataTable TimeData)
    {
        DateTime DayRangeStart = new DateTime(WhatDay.Year, WhatDay.Month, WhatDay.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime DayRangeEnd = new DateTime(WhatDay.Year, WhatDay.Month, WhatDay.AddDays(dayRange).Day, 0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan nightRest = new TimeSpan();


        foreach (DataRow drUnfiltered in TimeData.Rows)
        {
            DateTime sDate = DateTime.Parse(TimeData.Rows[0]["sDate"].ToString());
            DateTime eDate = DateTime.Parse(TimeData.Rows[0]["eDate"].ToString());

            //1. db-post cover range
            if (sDate < WhatDay && eDate > WhatDay.AddDays(dayRange))
            {
                nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(0);
                break;
            }
            //2. Post exists, start outside ends inside range
            if(sDate < WhatDay && eDate < WhatDay.AddDays(dayRange))
            {

               nightRest = (WhatDay.addDays(dayRange) - eDate)
               //More posts could exists that lower this value!!!
            }

            //3. Post exists, start inside ends outside range
            if ((sDate > WhatDay && sDate <WhatDay.AddDays(dayRange)) && eDate > WhatDay.AddDays(dayRange))
            {
                nightRest = (sDate - WhatDay);
                //More posts could exists that lower this value!!!
            }
        }
      return nightRest;
   }
```

I tried to write a different version, this code will compare different post trying to find the largest diff between them. But will fail to find posts that overlaps (no diff) and it will also fail with finding the correct diff with post that starts outside and ends inside the range and opposite.

`

```
            ///<Alternative></Alternative>
            //1. - No Data Rest = 24h x DayRange
            if (timeData.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(24 * dayRange);
            }

            ///<Alternative></Alternative>
            //2. - One Post, Compare to day start/end time
            if (timeData.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                DateTime sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(timeData.Rows[0]["sDate"].ToString());
                DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(timeData.Rows[0]["eDate"].ToString());

                TimeSpan range1 = (sDate - DayRangeStart);
                TimeSpan range2 = (DayRangeEnd - eDate);
                if (range1 > range2)
                {
                    nightRest = range1;
                }
                else
                {
                    nightRest = range2;
                }
            }

            ///<Alternative></Alternative>
            //3. - If DataTable containes more than 1 post, then loop through to calculate diffrence 
       between post and day start/end
            if (timeData.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                int i = 1;
                int RowCount = timeData.Rows.Count;
                foreach (DataRow dr in timeData.Rows)
                {
                    DateTime sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["sdate"]);
                    DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["edate"]);

                    DateTime prevPostSdate = new DateTime();
                    DateTime nextPostSdate = new DateTime();

                    //Only 1st time in loop
                    if (i != 1)
                    {
                        //Prev row                       
                        DataRow lastRow = timeData.Rows[(i - 1) - 1];
                        prevPostSdate = Convert.ToDateTime(lastRow["edate"]);
                        //prevPostEdate = Convert.ToDateTime(lastRow["edate"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prevPostSdate = DayRangeStart;
                    }
                    //If we are on EOF-post then dont get next post value, get instead range end value
                    if (i != RowCount)
                    {
                        //Next row
                        DataRow nextRow = timeData.Rows[(i - 1) + 1];
                        nextPostSdate = Convert.ToDateTime(nextRow["sdate"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nextPostSdate = DayRangeEnd;
                    }
                    ///<Compare>Type #1 
                    ///Sdate inside && eDate inside
                    ///</ Compare >                    
                    if (DayRangeStart < sDate && DayRangeEnd > eDate)
                    {
                        //Compair Range with Post-sdate & Post
                        //1. Range with Post-sdate
                        TimeSpan value1 = (sDate - prevPostSdate);
                        //2. Post-eDate with NextPostSdate
                        TimeSpan value2 = (nextPostSdate - eDate);

                        if (value1 > nightRest) nightRest = value1;
                        if (value2 > nightRest) nightRest = value2;
                    }
                    ///<Compare>Type #2 
                    ///Sdate outside && eDate inside
                    ///</ Compare >                   
                    if (DayRangeStart >= sDate && DayRangeEnd > eDate)
                    {
                        //Compair Range with Post-sdate & Post
                        //1. Range with Post-sdate
                        TimeSpan value1 = (nextPostSdate - eDate);                           
                        if (value1 > nightRest) nightRest = value1;

                    }
                    ///<Compare>Type #3
                    ///Sdate indise && eDate outside                    
                    ///</ Compare >
                    if (DayRangeStart < sDate && DayRangeEnd <= eDate)
                    {
                        //Compare Range Post-sdate & Post
                        //1. Range with Post-sdate
                        TimeSpan value1 = (sDate - prevPostSdate);
                        //Console.WriteLine(value1);
                        if (value1 > nightRest) nightRest = value1;
                    }
                    ///<Compare>Type #4 
                    ///Sdate outside  && eDate outside                    
                    ///</ Compare >
                    if (DayRangeStart >= sDate && DayRangeEnd <= eDate)
                    {

                        nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(0);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i manage to solve this. Probably some much better code out there but this does the work!

```
public DataTable FilterTable(DataTable table, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var filteredRows =
            from row in table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
            where (DateTime)row["sDate"] < endDate && startDate <= (DateTime)row["eDate"]
            select row;

        var filteredTable = table.Clone();
        filteredRows.ToList().ForEach(r => filteredTable.ImportRow(r));
        return filteredTable;
    }

public TimeSpan TimeNightRest(DateTime WhatDay, int dayRange, DataTable TimeData)
    {
        DateTime DayRangeStart = DateTime.Parse(WhatDay.ToShortDateString());
        DateTime DayRangeEnd = DateTime.Parse(DayRangeStart.AddDays(dayRange).ToShortDateString());
        TimeSpan nightRest = new TimeSpan();
        DataTable dtTime = FilterTable(TimeData, WhatDay, WhatDay.AddDays(dayRange));

        //1. - No posts
        if (dtTime.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(24 * dayRange);
        }

        //2. - One post Exists!
        if (dtTime.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            DateTime sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtTime.Rows[0]["sDate"].ToString());
            DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtTime.Rows[0]["eDate"].ToString());

            if (sDate < DayRangeEnd && DayRangeStart <= eDate)
            {
                TimeSpan range1 = (sDate - DayRangeStart);
                TimeSpan range2 = (DayRangeEnd - eDate);
                if (range1 > range2)
                {
                    nightRest = range1;
                }
                else
                {
                    nightRest = range2;
                }
                //Negative TimeSpans is ==> Zero
                if(nightRest < TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(24 * dayRange);
            }
        }

        //3. More then 1 post i db
        if (dtTime.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int RowCount = dtTime.Rows.Count;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtTime.Rows)
            {
                DateTime sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["sdate"]);
                DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["edate"]);


                if (sDate < DayRangeEnd && DayRangeStart <= eDate)
                {
                    DateTime prevPostSdate = new DateTime();
                    DateTime nextPostSdate = new DateTime();

                    //1st loop
                    if (i != 1)
                    {
                        //Prev row                       
                        DataRow lastRow = dtTime.Rows[(i - 1) - 1];
                        prevPostSdate = Convert.ToDateTime(lastRow["edate"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prevPostSdate = DayRangeStart;
                    }
                    //If we are on EOF-post then dont get next post value, get instead range end value
                    if (i != RowCount)
                    {
                        //Next row
                        DataRow nextRow = dtTime.Rows[(i - 1) + 1];
                        nextPostSdate = Convert.ToDateTime(nextRow["sdate"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nextPostSdate = DayRangeEnd;
                    }

                    if (DayRangeStart < sDate && DayRangeEnd > eDate)
                    {
                        TimeSpan value1 = (sDate - prevPostSdate);
                        TimeSpan value2 = (nextPostSdate - eDate);

                        if (value1 > nightRest) nightRest = value1;
                        if (value2 > nightRest) nightRest = value2;
                    }

                    if (DayRangeStart >= sDate && DayRangeEnd > eDate)
                    {
                        TimeSpan value1 = (nextPostSdate - eDate);
                        if (value1 > nightRest) nightRest = value1;
                    }

                    if (DayRangeStart < sDate && DayRangeEnd <= eDate)
                    {
                        TimeSpan value1 = (sDate - prevPostSdate);
                        if (value1 > nightRest) nightRest = value1;
                    }
                    if (DayRangeStart >= sDate && DayRangeEnd <= eDate)
                    {
                        nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(0);
                    }                       
                }
                else
                {
                    nightRest = TimeSpan.FromHours(24 * dayRange);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return nightRest;
    }
```